# Can a SharePoint Workflow start when an email is received in Outlook?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I have a shared folder in my outlook inbox that multiple users have as well. This email account was set up to receive voicemails as .wav file attachments. I wanted to know if it was possible to create a workflow in SharePoint that recognizes when a new email is received into this inbox, and initiates a workflow to begin?

Answer (score 1):

You can email-enable a document library in sharepoint and add a workflow to start automatically when new item is created. This should do it